# Create blank rows between rows in a dataset and then fill them using rows beneath. Python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two csv bank statement files that look similar to this and I am trying to make a graph of my total balance over time:

`Bank A                   Bank B
Date    Amount          Date     Amount
                        24/09      240
25/09     1400          23/09      200
23/09     1250          22/09      250
20/09     1235          21/09      200`

The problem is that if I simply merge them together and graph them; if there is only balance information for one account on a particular day then my balance would look like only this much. Eg. on the 22/09 it would show £250 (bank B) when its really £250(bank b)+£1235(bank a from the day before which is money I still have) = £1485.

Please let me know if there is a better solution but it seems that I need to insert blank rows into each dataset to look like this (for both):

`Bank A
Date    Amount
25/09     1400
24/09     (null)
23/09     1250 
22/09     (null)
21/09     (null)
20/09     1235`

...And then fill in the balance from the last time one was shown:
`Bank A
Date    Amount
25/09     1400
24/09     1250
23/09     1250 
22/09     1235
21/09     1235
20/09     1235`

Then the same for bank B:

`Bank B
Date    Amount
25/09    null
24/09    240
23/09    200
22/09    250
21/09    200`

Becomes:

`Bank B
Date    Amount
25/09    240
24/09    240
23/09    200
22/09    250
21/09    200`

Then I can sum the columns across each file and get a total balance on each day like this:

`Both Banks
Date    Amount
25/09    1640
24/09    1490
23/09    1450
22/09    1485
21/09    1235`

Thanks I hope this is clear enough (and clearer after edit.

Comment: Are you looking for the closing balance on each day? I.e. how much was at the end? Basically what should happen for the 25/09 for Bank A, when there are 2 balance values?

Comment: Yes correct. So where there are two balances in the day I would only need to keep the latest. I already have a way to remove these however - but if ?I could do it all in one step even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `pd.concat` and `bfill`

```
BB.Amount=np.nan
df=pd.concat([BA,BB.loc[~BB.Date.isin(BA.Date),:]],axis=0)
df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Date',ascending=False).bfill()
```

then, You got your `dataframe` `Bank A`

```
Out[1240]: 
    Date  Amount
0  25/09  1100.0
1  25/09  1400.0
4  24/09  1250.0
2  23/09  1250.0
5  22/09  1235.0
6  21/09  1235.0
3  20/09  1235.0
```

Edit :

```
dfA=dfA.set_index('Date')
dfB=dfB.set_index('Date')
dfA.groupby(level=0).sum()# add group by here 
dfB.groupby(level=0).sum()
idx=list(set(dfA.index).union(dfB.index))
dfA=dfA.reindex(idx).sort_index(ascending=False).bfill()
dfB=dfB.reindex(idx).sort_index(ascending=False).bfill()
dfA+dfB

Out[25]: 
       Amount
Date         
25/09  1640.0
24/09  1490.0
23/09  1450.0
22/09  1485.0
21/09  1435.0
20/09     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two dataframes on date and then sum the amount on axis 1

```
df = dfA.merge(dfB, on = 'Date', how = 'outer')
df['Amount'] = df.sum(1)
```

Now you can groupby date to sum across dates

```
df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().reset_index()
```

You get

```
    Date    Amount
0   20/09   1235.0
1   21/09   200.0
2   22/09   250.0
3   23/09   1450.0
4   24/09   240.0
5   25/09   2500.0
```

EDIT: Borrowing @wen's idx= ..

```
dfB.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
idx = list(set(dfA.index).union(dfB.index))
dfA = dfA.reindex(idx).sort_index().reset_index()
dfA['Amount'].ffill(inplace = True)
dfB = dfB.reindex(idx).sort_index().reset_index()
dfB['Amount'].ffill(inplace = True)
```

Now you merge and find sum

```
dfA.merge(dfB, on = 'Date',how = 'outer')
df['Amount'] = df.sum(1)
```

You get

```
    Date    Amount_x    Amount_y Amount
0   20/09   1235.0      NaN     1235.0
1   21/09   1235.0      200.0   1435.0
2   22/09   1235.0      250.0   1485.0
3   23/09   1250.0      200.0   1450.0
4   24/09   1250.0      240.0   1490.0
5   25/09   1400.0      240.0   1640.0
```

Comment: This is good but it doesn't solve the problem completely. I want to show the balance across **both** accounts on each day. So it shouldn't go up and down like that.

Comment: So what you produced is very close. However if you see on the 24/09 I won't have lost all my Bank B money but it looks like I have.
I need each date to include what balance I would have in total.

Comment: I am getting both columns simply showing Bank B data here.